# Building some functions on my own in C++ with OpenCV

Tags: c++

So I use C++ for some computer vision project with OpenCV. So after some projects, I've created some useful functions so that when every time I need it I don't have to write them again. For example, removing small blobs in binary maps, normalizing features, etc.

I built a namespace in a header file with a .cpp file to store my functions. I previously have been using MatLab heavily, and just wondering in C++ do I sort the functions I created into different classes, or put them under a namespace is good?

New to C++, just wondering what do people do for a situation like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I personally prefer creating several classes and putting them in the same namespace. This has been the common approach in two of my recent workplaces, at both of which such SDKs are commercially licensed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For free functions, your approach is fine.

For example:

**utils.hpp**

```
// headers, etc...

namespace Utils
{
    void someMethod( int someArg );
}
```

**utils.cpp**

```
#include "utils.hpp"

namespace Utils
{
    void someMethod( int someArg ) { /* implementation */ }
}
```

And, in your main source file:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "utils.hpp"

int main()
{
    Utils::someMethod( 123 );
    return 0;
}
```

For utility classes, you might want to enclose your classes into a namespace also.